# use a Magic Methods in an other Magic Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

```
class Juice:
    def __init__(self, name, capacity):
        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name + ' ('+str(self.capacity)+'L)')
    def __add__(self,other):
        all_name = self.name + "&" + other.name
        all_capacity = self.capacity + other.capacity
        return(all_name+str(all_capacity))
a = Juice('Orange', 1.5)
b = Juice('Apple', 2.0)
result = a + b
print(result)
```

I want to use `__str__` in `__add__` not `str()` . so how can I do it ? can I do if ? Again in `__add__` in the return line I want to use the magic method str() not the original str()

Comment: Just call `self.__str__()`? It's not clear what you're actually having trouble with. Also, why would you want to completely subvert a system that has a very clear purpose?

Comment: Why do you want to use `__str__`? `all_capacity` is not a `Juice` object, it's an `int`, you can't use `__str__` there.

Comment: It's not a good idea for `__add__` to return a different type. It means you won't be able to write `a + b + c`, because the first addition will return a `str` instead of `Juice`.

Comment: `str(obj)` calls `obj.__str__()`

Comment: @RootTwo not always

Comment: return(all_name+self.__str__(all_capacity))
TypeError: __str__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @PeterWood, per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str) "If neither encoding nor errors is given, str(object) returns object.__str__(), which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of object."

Comment: @PeterWood: The exception is basically just the case where `__str__` isn't explicitly defined, in which case it falls back to `__repr__`. But `__str__` gets priority, so if there *is* a `__str__` defined on the class (and not the instance, because special methods are special, but calling them directly doesn't use the special path) the two are equivalent.

Comment: @HackerBoy what makes you think you should pass `all_capacity` to `self.__str__`? Your definition takes no parameters (other than `self`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is because `str` isn't being called on your object and is instead being called on all capacity, which is just a normal Float.

One option that is simple enough is to just create a new object. If you don't want to do this you will need to restructure your `__str__` implementation. Here is an example of what you might do.

```
class Juice:
    def __init__(self, name, capacity):
        self.name = name
        self.capacity = capacity

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name + ' ('+str(self.capacity)+'L)')

    def __add__(self,other):
        all_name = self.name + "&" + other.name
        all_capacity = self.capacity + other.capacity
        return str(Juice(all_name, all_capacity))

a = Juice('Orange', 1.5)
b = Juice('Apple', 2.0)
result = a + b
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Orange&Apple (3.5L)
```